# MySQL query all item in groom meet criteria

Tags: mysql

I have I table which looks like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server_orders` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_order_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,     
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

with values

```
INSERT INTO `server_orders` (`id`, `group_order_id`, `status`) VALUES
(1, '1', '1'),
 (2, '2', '50'),
 (3, '2', '100'),
 (4, '2', '1'),
 (5, '3', '100'),
 (6, '3', '100'),
 (7, '4', '1'),

;
```

I want to select all of them  with status 100 only if all rows with same group id have status 100 so in this case it will be id 5 and 6 with group_order_id 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work using `COUNT` with `CASE`:

```
select * 
from server_orders
where group_order_id in (
  select group_order_id
  from server_orders
  group by group_order_id
  having count(id) = count(case when status = 100 then 1 end)
  )
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b96f3/2)

It works by comparing the count of all the records for each group_order_id to the count when the status is equal to 100.